# Не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "int"

Tags: c++

> Ошибка: не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "int" в "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>"

```
#include <string>
    
int main()
{
    std::string z = 122; // тут ошибка, почему?
}
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону std::to_string();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ кроется непосредственно в заголовке вопроса:

> не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "int"

У `std::string` нет конструктора, который неявно приводил бы к преобразованию целого числа `int` в строковый тип.

В данном случае подойдёт вариант с [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), который породит строковое представление переданного числа:

```
auto z = std::to_string(122);
```

Но можно и просто записать константу строкой, для этого достаточно добавить кавычки:

```
std::string z = "122";
```